# How to generate a localized relative time span string such as the Android alarm?

Tags: android

I want to produce a similar string as the Android alarm does when setting an alarm.

*Example:*
 - "Alarm set for 6 days, 10 hours, and 9 minutes from now."
 - "Alarm set for 10 hours, and 9 minutes from now."
 - "Alarm set for 9 minutes from now."

I'm able to use:

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(alarm.triggerTime, 
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), 
                    DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, 
                    flags).toString();
```

Which produces a message something like ***"in 19 hours"***. I can't seem to be able to produce something more like ***"in 19 hours and 5 minutes"*** or ***"in 5 days, 10 hours, and 30 minutes"***.

I want to figure out how to achieve this if possible using Android localized helper classes such as `DateUtils`.  I would hate to have to stitch strings possibly causing issues on other languages.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `Eclipse IDE` then try to install `GrepCode_Plugin` from this tutorial [GrepCode_Plugin](http://grepcode.com/eclipse)

Once you get done with that in `GrepCode Search` box search with `android.text.format.DateUtils`. It will list you all files. Try to download the latest one.

Get the method from that file and modify it according to your needs.

For your Reference I am going put the method listed in `android 4.1.1_r1`

```
public static CharSequence getRelativeTimeSpanString(long time, long now, long minResolution,
            int flags) {
    Resources r = Resources.getSystem();
    boolean abbrevRelative = (flags & (FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE | FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL)) != 0;

    boolean past = (now >= time);
    long duration = Math.abs(now - time);

    int resId;
    long count;
    if (duration < MINUTE_IN_MILLIS && minResolution < MINUTE_IN_MILLIS) {
        count = duration / SECOND_IN_MILLIS;
        if (past) {
            if (abbrevRelative) {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.abbrev_num_seconds_ago;
            } else {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.num_seconds_ago;
            }
        } else {
            if (abbrevRelative) {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.abbrev_in_num_seconds;
            } else {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.in_num_seconds;
            }
        }
    } else if (duration < HOUR_IN_MILLIS && minResolution < HOUR_IN_MILLIS) {
        count = duration / MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
        if (past) {
            if (abbrevRelative) {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.abbrev_num_minutes_ago;
            } else {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.num_minutes_ago;
            }
        } else {
            if (abbrevRelative) {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.abbrev_in_num_minutes;
            } else {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.in_num_minutes;
            }
        }
    } else if (duration < DAY_IN_MILLIS && minResolution < DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
        count = duration / HOUR_IN_MILLIS;
        if (past) {
            if (abbrevRelative) {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.abbrev_num_hours_ago;
            } else {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.num_hours_ago;
            }
        } else {
            if (abbrevRelative) {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.abbrev_in_num_hours;
            } else {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.in_num_hours;
            }
        }
    } else if (duration < WEEK_IN_MILLIS && minResolution < WEEK_IN_MILLIS) {
        count = getNumberOfDaysPassed(time, now);
        if (past) {
            if (abbrevRelative) {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.abbrev_num_days_ago;
            } else {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.num_days_ago;
            }
        } else {
            if (abbrevRelative) {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.abbrev_in_num_days;
            } else {
                resId = com.android.internal.R.plurals.in_num_days;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // We know that we won't be showing the time, so it is safe to pass
        // in a null context.
        return formatDateRange(null, time, time, flags);
    }

    String format = r.getQuantityString(resId, (int) count);
    return String.format(format, count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I already looked at the source you posted and was able to confirm I can't get what I need from that function. With this you only get days, hours, or min strings but could never get them all into one sentence as what I want. :/